# why buildin login_required decorator not check user.is_active

Tags: python, django, security, django-authentication

Why django buildin login_required decorator do not check is_active flag ?

I have to use another decorator or auth type to secure this issue?

My solution for this is override that decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required as login

def login_required(fn):
    @login
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs) if args[0].user.is_active else HttpResponse()
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Why should it check? You can't log in at all if is_active is False.

Comment: You are correct that it doesn't check whether a user is active [relevant source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.2/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L39). I can't speak as to why except to guess so I won't answer but my guess would be that they want it to do exactly what the function name implies - principle of least astonishment and all.

Comment: Problem is when I deactivate user account after logging in. @chucksmash U have right about that principle, but I am surpriced about this. IMO login_required is primitive...

Comment: Ahh, I see where you are coming from. In that case, I'd say you should add logic to invalidate the session/logout the user to your code that marks them as inactive.

Comment: It's [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) that the `login_required` decorator does not check `is_active`. If you search [Django trac](https://code.djangoproject.com/search) or the [Django developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/django-developers) mailing list for 'login_required is_active', you'll see several tickets and posts discussing this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

[Modern Django states](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) :

> The login_required decorator does NOT check the is_active flag on a
> user, but the default AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS reject inactive users.

I have tested this and inactive users can't log in when using the default authentication backend with the `login_required` decorator.